# PL/Sql procedure: my cursor is ordered by date but the output that is written to a table is not ordered the same

Tags: plsql, cursors

Only getting my head around cursor loops and the likes lately, so might be something very simple with my code that's causing the problem

I am using a cursor to spool through customer data to create an xml file.  It needs to be sorted by date so that the most recent data is at the bottom of the xml file.

when I run the sql for the cursor, i can see the data is ordered by date. But when I run the entire procedure and check the output, it seems to be ordered by date but on closer inspection some of the records are not in the correct order.

here is the code I'm running.  I've omitted a lot of the query as its just xml padding, but I don't think that should make a difference.

the output is written to a table, which i then copy and paste into notepad++.  When checking the output table I can see that the order is wrong

```
drop table recs_xml_output;
create table recs_xml_output (XML_STRING VARCHAR2 (4000 char));

declare

  PROCEDURE p_generate_ohmpi_record 
  IS
 
    lv_string           VARCHAR2(10000 CHAR) := NULL;
    lv_date_format      VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)    := 'YYYY-MM-DD';
    lv_time_format      VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)    := 'HH24:MI:SS';
    n_id                PLS_INTEGER          := NULL;

    CURSOR c_patient_xml IS
    select *         
        from sbyn_transaction T
         where  timestamp >= '07-JAN-22 11.58.02.139977000'
        and timestamp <=  '07-JAN-22 17.51.26.054240000'
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP; 
    
  begin
          
     for v_patient_xml in c_patient_xml

      loop
        
       lv_string := n_id||'<Person><SourceID>';
        lv_string := lv_string||v_patient_xml.lid||'</SourceID><PPSN>'||v_patient_xml.lid||'</PPSN>';
       
        lv_string := lv_string||'<PPSNLastUpdated>';
        lv_string := lv_string||TO_CHAR( v_patient_xml.pps_number_updated,lv_date_format )||'T'||TO_CHAR( v_patient_xml.pps_number_updated,lv_time_format)||'</PPSNLastUpdated>';
    
        lv_string := lv_string||'<Birth>';
        
         IF v_patient_xml.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL THEN
         lv_string := lv_string||'<DateOfBirth>'||TO_CHAR( v_patient_xml.date_of_birth,lv_date_format )||'T'||TO_CHAR( v_patient_xml.date_of_birth,lv_time_format)||'</DateOfBirth>';
        else lv_string := lv_string||'<DateOfBirth></DateOfBirth>';
        END IF;
        
       ...
        
        insert into recs_xml_output VALUES (lv_string);

      END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
  end p_generate_ohmpi_record; 

begin
    
   p_generate_ohmpi_record;
  

end;
/
```

Comment: When you say "some of the records are not in the correct order" are you referring to the records in the XML document (btw, there are better ways of producing XML than manually writing out strings, plus you can do `to_char(<date>, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss')` so you don't need to split the date format string up), or the records in the table? Because bog-standard heap tables have no intrinsic ordering to them; the only way to guarantee data is returned in the order you need it to is to add an order by clause to the select statement.

Comment: i'm referring to the order of the records populated in the recs_xml_output table.  it's from here that I copy and paste the records into a text file and save as xml

if there's a better way of producing xml i'd definitely give it a go, as this is very cumbersome as you can see

thank you for the to_char(<date>, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') tip, ill update the script

" the only way to guarantee data is returned in the order you need it to is to add an order by clause to the select statement"
i do have an order by in the select statement for the cursor - is this what you mean?

Comment: You're not outputting the column you're ordering the cursor by in the table, so what makes you think the data is out of order? If you need the table to output results in the required order, you'll need to add the ordering-column into the table and then select from it using that column to order the results, e.g. `create table recs_xml_output (tstamp timestamp, XML_STRING VARCHAR2 (4000 char));` `select xml_string from recs_xml_output order by tstamp);`

Comment: the sql i have above is a stripped down version of the actual query.  i am ordering by a column called transaction_date, which is in the output

Comment: ahh ok, i see what you mean. thank you for this, i will give it a try!

Comment: What is the purpose of your script? Are you literally just wanting to output the results of your cursor as a single xml document?

Comment: yes that is the gist of it.  one line for each record; name, address, DOB data

Comment: Boneist, what is the syntax then for inserting the tstamp value into my output table, something like this

 insert into recs_xml_output (tdate,xmlstring) VALUES (transaction_date,lv_string);

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you aren't storing the ordering column in your output table, and you're relying on the rows being returned from that table in the order they were inserted.

Unfortunately, as it's a heap table, the order of insertion is not necessarily going to be the same as the order you retrieve them. In order to guarantee a specific ordering of the rows when selecting from a table, you need to have an order by clause.

Therefore you could do something like:

```
create table recs_xml_output (tstamp timestamp, XML_STRING VARCHAR2 (4000 char));

PROCEDURE p_generate_ohmpi_record 
IS
  ...

  CURSOR c_patient_xml IS
  select *         
  from   sbyn_transaction T
  where  timestamp >= '07-JAN-22 11.58.02.139977000'
  and    timestamp <=  '07-JAN-22 17.51.26.054240000'
  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP; 

begin
      
  for v_patient_xml in c_patient_xml
  loop
    ...

    insert into recs_xml_output (tstamp, xml_string)
    VALUES (v_patient_xml.timestamp, lv_string);

  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;

end p_generate_ohmpi_record;

select *
from   recs_xml_output
order by tstamp;
```

However, if your ultimate goal is simply to take your rows and output them as XML, you can do it in a single SQL statement:

```
WITH sbyn_transaction AS (SELECT 1 lid,
                                 to_timestamp('11/01/2022 11:25:57.136468', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') pps_number_updated,
                                 to_date('01/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_birth,
                                 'info 1' info_column
                          FROM dual
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 2 lid,
                                 to_timestamp('11/01/2022 11:23:46.115329', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') pps_number_updated,
                                 to_date('06/10/1979', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_birth,
                                 'info 2' info_column
                          FROM dual
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 3 lid,
                                 to_timestamp('11/01/2022 11:24:08.951232', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') pps_number_updated,
                                 NULL date_of_birth,
                                 'info 3' info_column
                          FROM dual
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT 4 lid,
                                 to_timestamp('11/01/2022 11:23:17.468329', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6') pps_number_updated,
                                 to_date('29/03/1957', 'dd/mm/yyyy') date_of_birth,
                                 'info 4' info_column
                          FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table with data in it; main query below:
SELECT st.*,
       XMLELEMENT("Person",
                  XMLFOREST(lid AS "SourceID",
                            lid AS "PPSN",
                            to_char(pps_number_updated, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') AS "PPSNLastUpdated"),
                  XMLELEMENT("Birth",
                             XMLFOREST(to_char(date_of_birth, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') AS "DateOfBirth") AS "Birth"),
                  XMLFOREST(info_column AS "SomeData")).getclobval() xml_record
FROM   sbyn_transaction st
ORDER BY pps_number_updated;

       LID PPS_NUMBER_UPDATED                                DATE_OF_BIRTH INFO_COLUMN XML_RECORD
---------- ------------------------------------------------- ------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         4 11-JAN-22 11.23.17.468329000                      29/03/1957    info 4      <Person><SourceID>4</SourceID><PPSN>4</PPSN><PPSNLastUpdated>2022-01-11T11:23:17</PPSNLastUpdated><Birth><DateOfBirth>1957-03-29T00:00:00</DateOfBirth></Birth><SomeData>info 4</SomeData></Person>
         2 11-JAN-22 11.23.46.115329000                      06/10/1979    info 2      <Person><SourceID>2</SourceID><PPSN>2</PPSN><PPSNLastUpdated>2022-01-11T11:23:46</PPSNLastUpdated><Birth><DateOfBirth>1979-10-06T00:00:00</DateOfBirth></Birth><SomeData>info 2</SomeData></Person>
         3 11-JAN-22 11.24.08.951232000                                    info 3      <Person><SourceID>3</SourceID><PPSN>3</PPSN><PPSNLastUpdated>2022-01-11T11:24:08</PPSNLastUpdated><Birth></Birth><SomeData>info 3</SomeData></Person>
         1 11-JAN-22 11.25.57.136468000                      01/01/2000    info 1      <Person><SourceID>1</SourceID><PPSN>1</PPSN><PPSNLastUpdated>2022-01-11T11:25:57</PPSNLastUpdated><Birth><DateOfBirth>2000-01-01T00:00:00</DateOfBirth></Birth><SomeData>info 1</SomeData></Person>
```

Comment: that's actually class! I've used XMELEMENT before when searching for certain records, never dawned on my I can use it to simply generate the xml output without having to faff about with the tags the way I was doing it.  
You've really helped me out of a pickle here, i really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: If you need to output all the rows in a single XML document, you can use `XMLAGG` to aggregate the results into one row - you'll also need to put it inside another `XMLELEMENT` to put the root tag on it

Comment: legend! thanks a million
I am now ready for tomorrow's stand up :)